# UITableView returns the same items on each section

Tags: ios, nsindexpath

I created a table with sections. Each section has a date (2014-03-23) as a title and under each date I want to populate a list of games to be played that day. When I run the app the table gets the section title fine (date of game), but every section has the same matches list. I want to have the games match under the section date.
I know i need to include indexPath.section in the CellForRowsAtIndexPath but I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

Here's my code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
            {

                return gamesArray.count;
            }


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        {

            uniqueArray = [[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:dateSection] array];
            return [uniqueArray count];



        }


-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
        {
            return [self.dateSection objectAtIndex:section];
        }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
         //NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"games cell-%ld-%ld", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"games cell";
        //NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell-%d-%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];


        CustomInboxCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = (CustomInboxCell *)[[CustomInboxCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        PFObject *post = [gamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
        [cell.teamsLabel setText:[post  objectForKey:@"teams"]];
        [cell.liveRepeatLabel setText:[post objectForKey:@"liveRepeat"]];
        [cell.gameTimeLabel setText:[post objectForKey:@"gameTime"]];

        return cell;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//======================================================
//I decided to use a predicate to filter and get the number of items per date(Number of games per date)

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    NSString *sectionTitle = [uniqueArray objectAtIndex:section];

    if (section >=0) {

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"gameDate == %@",sectionTitle];
        NSLog(@"section name = %@", sectionTitle);
        NSArray *filtered = [gamesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        NSLog(@"filtered = %@",filtered);
        return filtered.count;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

//I just need to iterate through every date and return the number of games per date. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You need a separate array for each section of the table.  In `numberOfRowsForSection`, you need to return a `count` for the array that corresponds to the given `section`.

---

Here's an example. The data for the table is stored in an NSArray called `tableData`.  The array has one entry for each **section** of the table.  Each entry in `tableData` is an NSDictionary.  The NSDictionary has two keys, `title` and `items`.  The `title` key corresponds to an NSString that serves as the title for the table section.  The `items` key corresponds to an NSArray that has the row information for the table section.

The table is organized into two sections like this

```
Fruits
    Apples
    Oranges
Animals
    Dog
    Cat
    Horse
    Cow
```

Here's the code

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *tableData;
@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;

    NSDictionary *fruits, *animals;

    fruits  = @{ @"title" : @"Fruits" , @"items" : @[@"Apples", @"Oranges"]            };
    animals = @{ @"title" : @"Animals", @"items" : @[@"Dog", @"Cat", @"Horse", @"Cow"] };

    self.tableData = @[fruits, animals];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return( self.tableData.count );
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSDictionary *sectionData = self.tableData[section];
    NSArray *items = sectionData[@"items"];
    return( items.count );
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSDictionary *sectionData = self.tableData[section];
    NSString *title = sectionData[@"title"];
    return( title );
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SomeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSDictionary *sectionData = self.tableData[indexPath.section];
    NSArray *items = sectionData[@"items"];
    NSString *name = items[indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = name;

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: In my case I have only one table: 

Games:
      teams
      stadium
      time
      date
I want to create a section of dates, with the corresponding games inside.

Comment: That's ok, but in `numberOfRowsInSection` you'll have to do some calculations to determine how many rows belong to the specified `section`.  Also, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you'll need to find the correct item for the specified `indexPath`.

Comment: Hi @Walter I just got the message, but only the first part that said you were stuck.  Since the message has been changed, I take it that you were able to get unstuck?

Comment: Not really, took a couple of steps back to look at what you sent me. 
I tried following your advice but it didn't work for me.
Im currently working on the numberOfRowsInSection, and still need help.

Comment: So I went back and took a fresh look at what you're doing. What's needed is an example of the data that you're trying to manipulate. I think the solution to this problem is to take the data that you have and rearrange it into the format that makes it easy to drive the table.

Comment: look at the last edit on my code. It's working the way I wanted just wondering how it can be optimized. Thanks again

Comment: Ah ok, so the predicate works.  I suggest creating a `filtered` array for each date in the `uniqueArray`, and create a dictionary where the `key` is the date, and the `object` is the filtered array.  Do this once any time you update the `gamesArray`.  That way, you don't have to constantly rerun the predicate, you can simply get the filtered array from the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

This is a data set problem, you need to have a separate dataset prepared for each section of your tableview and iterate them using the index path (row, section) properties in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method. If you can do NSLog and share your dataset, it would be more helpful to answer accurately. Hope this helps.

Comment: I would recommend having an NSDictionary with key-value pairing for each section and the corresponding date set. Then use this inside your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Printing description of self->gamesArray:
<__NSArrayM 0x1702465a0>(
<gamesToWatch:S1RtVOx9n7:(null)> {
    author = "<PFUser:eOHwGnoZc9>";
    channels = "beIN Sports en Espa\U00f1ol\nbeIN Sports Play";
    gameDate = "2014-03-23";
    gameTime = "17:00";
    liveRepeat = Live;
    teams = "Almer\U00eda vs Real Sociedad";
},
<gamesToWatch:O74Ganxsiz:(null)> {
    author = "<PFUser:eOHwGnoZc9>";
    channels = "Premium Sports";
    gameDate = "2014-03-24";
    gameTime = "16:00";
    liveRepeat = Live;
    teams = "Vit\U00f3ria Set\U00fabal vs Estoril";
},